# ¿Como validar si un numero esta dentro de un rango con valores DECIMALES?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, windows

Hola Compañeros una pregunta sencilla estoy tratando de validar un textbox con el evento leave de manera que cuando se cambie el foco del mismo valide si esta dentro del rango de números a mas/menos Explico rápidamente
Diámetro = 1.50 toleranciaMas = 1.50 + 0.05 toleranciaMenos = 1.50- 0.05
tengo el siguiente código, el cual calcula correctamente pero en la parte de la condición siempre se va directo a "si no"  (aun así el dato sea correcto)

```
//Validacion De Diametros
    private void txtbDE_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal ValDiamEx = Convert.ToDecimal(txtbxDiamExt.Text);
        decimal toleranciamas = Convert.ToDecimal(txtbxDiamE.Text);
        decimal toleranciamenos = Convert.ToDecimal(txtbxDiamE.Text);
        decimal diametromas;
        decimal diametromenos;

        diametromenos = ValDiamEx - toleranciamenos;
        diametromas = ValDiamEx + toleranciamas;

        //MessageBox.Show("variables" + ValDiamEx +  diametromenos+ diametromas);


        if ((diametromenos >= ValDiamEx) && (diametromas  <= ValDiamEx))
            {
             // Dentro del rango deja escribir
             MessageBox.Show("Esta Dentro del rango Deja Escribir");
         }
         else
         {
             // Fuera del rango NO deja escribir
             MessageBox.Show("Esta Fuera del rango NO Deja Escribir");
         }

    }
```

Edito la pregunta con la impresión de pantalla de las variables que estoy utilizando

[image: Impresión de variables]

Comment: Noto dos detalles 1. Los valores máximo y mínimo son calculados a partir del valor leído, no a partir de un valor de control de modo que si el condicional está bien escrito, este siempre va a ser verdadero. 2. Las comparaciones sólo serían verdaderas si el valor está fuera del rango (escribes los signos al revés) y como el rango se crea usando el valor ingresado, siempre está dentro; de modo que la condición es falsa. Por eso no obtienes nunca un valor válido.

Comment: ¿Cual es el valor al que debe acercarse el dato ingresado? **Quizás 1.50** si es así: `diametromenos = 1.50 - 0.05` y `diametromas = 1.50 + 0.05` o algo similar.

Comment: Una vez establecida la tolerancia, hay algo con qué comparar. Un valor ***a*** siempre estará entre ***a-x*** y ***a+x***. Como lo enfocaste no tiene sentido la comparación y falla por estar mal escrita (por ser contradictoria)

Comment: El valor que estoy tratando de validar seria como este ejemplo Diametro = 1.50 (0.05+/-) es decir rangoMayor = 1.55 y rangoMenor = 1.45 (necesito validar que el numero ingresado en el input este entre rangoMenor y rangoMayor) espero Explicarme correctamente

Comment: entonces escribe: `cotasuperior = 1.55; cotainferior = 1.45; if( (cotainferior <= ValDiamEx) && ( ValDiamEx <= cotasuperior) ) { 'esta en el rango' } else { 'fuera del rango' }`

Comment: Creo que estas colocando la validación al revés, creo que seria así: `if (ValDiamEx >= diametromenos && ValDiamEx <= diametromas)`

Comment: Extrayendo los valores quedaría: `if (1.5 >= 1.45 && 1.5 <= 1.55)`

Comment: Créanme que he hecho casi todas las combinaciones en el IF pero no logro dar con el resultado, justamente he cambiado 2 cosas segun su ayuda 
1.- el parametro lo tomo directamente del textbox y no de una variable 
2.- he cambiado el if de esta manera 
if (( Convert.ToDecimal(txtbxDiamExt.Text) >= diametromenos ) && ( Convert.ToDecimal(txtbxDiamExt.Text) <=  diametromas ))

Comment: Ejecuta el programa en [modo depuración pasa a paso](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019) y revisa que valores están llegando o imprimas en la consola esos valores para que puedas depurar y revisar que pasa. Cualquier captura de imagen o log en la consola lo adjuntas a la pregunta.

Comment: he hecho ya algunas pruebas sencillas si obserbas el codigo de la pregunta hay una linea comentada  `//MessageBox.Show("variables" + ValDiamEx +  diametromenos+ diametromas);` en ella imprimo las variables y efectivamente los datos de los calculos llegan de forma correcta

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa si observas no solamente coloca la validación al revés. Valida contra sí mismo de modo que todos los valores la pasarían cuando la corrija. Ya le indiqué como debe hacerla.

Comment: @quevedo `if ( Convert.ToDecimal(txtbxDiamExt.Text) >= diametromenos &&  Convert.ToDecimal(txtbxDiamExt.Text) <= diametromas)` hice lo de tus "indicaciones" pero sigo sin llegar al resultado

Comment: Te faltan paréntesis && liga más fuerte que >= : `if ( (Convert.ToDecimal(txtbxDiamExt.Text) >= diametromenos ) &&  (Convert.ToDecimal(txtbxDiamExt.Text) <= diametromas) ) {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error en tu código está en el condicional; tendría que ser así:

```
if ((diametromenos <= ValDiamEx) && (ValDiamEx <= diametromas))
{
    // dentro del rango
}
else
{
    // fuera del rango
}
```

Si lo quieres hacer bonito, puedes crear un método que indique si un valor está dentro de un rango:

```
public bool InsideRange(decimal p_Valor, decimal p_CotaInf, decimal p_CotaSup)
{
      return (p_CotaInf <= p_Valor) && (p_Valor <= p_CotaSup);
}
```

En tu caso lo llamaríamos así:

```
if (InsideRange(ValDiamEx, diametromenos, diametromas))
    // dentro del rango
}
else
{
    // fuera del rango
}
```

No obstante tu valor ValDiamEx siempre va a estar dentro de las tolerancias, ya que las estás creando en base al valor de ValDiamEx.

Comment: Gracias por tus observaciones, una pregunta que cambios debería hacer para que ValDiamEx no este siempre dentro de la tolerancia y pueda validar correctamente el inputbox, es decir contra que debería hacer la comparación. GRACIAS

Comment: Cable aclarar que las tolerancias se están tomando del mismo txtbox ya que ES la misma tolerancia hacia MAS y hacia MENOS es decir si el diámetro es 5.0  podrá tener una tolerancia de 0.05 hacia MAS y de igual manera 0.05 hacia MENOS GRACIAS

Comment: Yo lo veo un poco sin sentido lo que pretendes. Para mí las tolerancias suelen ser las mismas arriba o abajo. Según lo veo cuando metes por ejemplo 150 y la tolerancia es +/- 0.05 lo que obtenemos es un valor de referencia marcando o definiendo un rango de medida para la tolerancia de forma que un segundo valor sí podría ser comparado en dicho rango para ver si cumple. Por ejemplo, si la pieza que he fabricado mide 150.04 estaría dentro y cumple las especificaciones marcadas por las tolerancias. Pero en tu código no existe ese segundo valor para precisamente ver si cumple con los parámetros.